# How to append objects on a file on Java?

Tags: java, file, object, arraylist, append

I'm trying to do an app on Java in which I need to save ArrayLists on a file. I was looking for how to do this and I found the next code:

```
ArrayList<Expediente> al = new ArrayList<Expediente>();
Expediente exp = new Expediente("Expediente data");

try{
    File file = new File("Pathname");
    FileOutputStream ofs = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ofs);
    oos.writeObject(al);
    oos.close();
    ofs.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My problem now is that if I want to save the same ArrayList but with another data or if I reopen the file, the first data that is in the file is overwritten.

Could someone tell how to append this new data on the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Java API docs?

Comment: I think this is duplicate to this. There is good answer there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Yeah, I know about the FileWriter and the PrintWriter, but I need to write Objects, not Strings. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `append` flag to true in the FileOutputStream ctor.

```
FileOutputStream ofs = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

See

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: Thank you very much :) I didn't though about this option :s hahaha

Comment: You're welcome. And I don't blame you -- I've been a Java programmer for 20 years, was a Java architect for Sun, wrote a lot of the certification exam questions and reviewed them all -- and I just habitually go read the API docs *any* time I'm doing Java. There are just too many details to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
FileOutputStream ofs = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

You can use

```
FileOutputStream ofs = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

See the Java API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Comment: Thank you very much :) I didn't though about this option :s hahaha